# Are there any online Arabic dictionaries that include diacritics for pronunciation?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, arabic

Arabic is written in the [Arabic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Table_of_basic_letters) and, like Hebrew and Persian, is written without vowels. This makes it hard for a learner to decipher the exact pronunciation of any Arabic word without referring to an audio source or a dictionary that includes [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics).

Are there any online Arabic dictionaries (either paid or free) that include diacritics (especially conjugated verbs)?

Answer (score 6):

- [Reverso](https://dictionary.reverso.net/arabic-english/) (diacritics and romanization, including of conjugations)
- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Arabic_language) (diacritics and romanization, including of conjugations)
- [Dict](https://www.dict.com/arabic-english/) (diacritics and romanization)
- [Bab.la](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/arabic-english) (diacritics and romanization)
- [Almaany](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/) (diacritics)
- [Lane](http://lexicon.quranic-research.net/index.html) (diacritics)
- [ArabicLexicon](http://arabiclexicon.hawramani.com/) (collection of classical dictionaries, some with diacritics)
- [Dicts](https://www.dicts.info/dictionary.php?l1=English&l2=Arabic) (romanization)
- [Alpheios](https://alpheios.net/) incorporates Lane and Salmoné's dictionaries into the software (both also in ArabicLexicon)

Comment: I don't see any diactritics in Reverso.